# How to match only current node in xsl template rule?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input to an xsl transform:

```
<root>
    <Section>
        <Section>
            <Type>Table</Type>
        </Section>
    </Section>
</root>
```

I am trying to apply a template, and match only the current Section node, but the match expression on an `xsl:template` will match any sub-section as well.

Is there a way to limit match to only the current node?

I am applying this xsl stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section" />
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Section[Type]">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<output>
        Table
</output>
```

The template matching `Section[Type]` is matching the subsection, but the result i am looking for is when `<xsl:apply-templates select="Section" />` is called, nothing should be matched because the current Section has no `Type` element.

Or, do i have to use call-template for this type of situation?

The other option would be to match the on Section/Type, but I want to avoid using `..` in experssion to get back to the parent node, only for sake of clarity in the code.

Comment: How about to restrict like `root/Section` or `Section[Section] `?

Comment: The nesting can be any depth for problem i am dealing with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The confusion you have is because of XSLT's [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule), that get applied when the XSLT processor can find no matching template in your XSLT file. In your case, when you do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Section" />
```

It will look for a template that matches the first `Section`, but there is no matching template in your XSLT because the one you do have only matches `Section` elements that have a child `Type`. The built-in template then kicks in, which is effectively this..

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

That is to say, it will apply templates that match the child elements; your sub-section.

The solution is to add a matching template for `Section` in your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="Section" />
```

Because this is not quantified with a condition, this will have lower priority than the one matching `Section[Type]` should you only have one such `Section` in your XSLT.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section" />
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Section" />

    <xsl:template match="Section[Type]">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your XML, it just outputs `<output/>`, but if you were to apply it to this...

```
<root>
    <Section>
        <Type>Table</Type>
    </Section>
</root>
```

The output would be this...

```
<output>
    Table
</output>
```

You can read up on template priority at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict

Comment: I can't thank you enough.  Its one of those times I'm thrown into a project without sufficient time to get a grasp on the tecnology, in this case XSLT, and learning as I go.